# system not booting

Tags: bios

My sys has following alert msgs.booting from hard disk drive. system security, user password required.typer ur password, then press enter.
bios saving settings are hidden. no f10 key working in bios... what to do? pls tell the solution....

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to enter a password before you can edit the BIOS settings. I recommend looking through the manual for your chipset for a default password or, if the pc isn't yours contact your admin.

If none of those options work. There is a method of removing the BIOS battery (it should look like a watch battery) for a minute or 2. Then plug it back in and try to access the BIOS again; the password requirement should be gone. But don't do this without first looking a guide for you specific chipset.

Answer (score 1):

See the article [How to Bypass or Remove a BIOS Password](http://www.technibble.com/how-to-bypass-or-remove-a-bios-password/)

It describes 3 methods:

1. Removing the CMOS Battery
2. Using the !BIOS freeware utility
3. Using the manufacturer backdoor password